# Why does the time between frame acquisition get progressively worse?

Tags: matlab

I'm attempting to acquire frames from two webcams simultaneously.

Here's two graphs to show what I mean:
[image: 10 frames]

[image: 30 frames]

Here's the code:

```
% Acquire cameras.
cam1 = videoinput('winvideo', 1, 'YUY2_800x600');
cam1.FramesPerTrigger = 30;
triggerconfig(cam1, 'manual');

cam2 = videoinput('winvideo', 2, 'YUY2_800x600');
cam2.FramesPerTrigger = 30;
triggerconfig(cam2, 'manual');

% Get all frame rates available for these cameras.
srcCam1 = getselectedsource(cam1);
srcCam2 = getselectedsource(cam1);
frameRates = set(srcCam1, 'FrameRate');

% Configure frame rate.
srcCam1.FrameRate = frameRates{4};
srcCam2.FrameRate = frameRates{4};

% Start cams for acquisition. 
start([cam1, cam2]);
trigger([cam1, cam2]);

[frames1, timeStamp1] = getdata(cam1);
[frames2, timeStamp2] = getdata(cam2);

% Plot.
plot(timeStamp1, 'x'); hold on;
plot(timeStamp2, 'x');
xlabel('Frame Index');
ylabel('Time(s)');
legend('cam1', 'cam2');
```

Originally I was just starting the cameras and acquiring the frames without manually triggering their acquisition. This provided a stable interval between each camera acquiring a frame but the interval was too large (1.5 seconds between frames).

I found a thread that suggested manually triggering the cameras. This seems to work great in the first two frames but then as it continues the interval between each camera acquiring a frame gets larger and larger.

Could anyone please suggest a way of improving this or point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: Can you check/post the RAM usage while running the code as well as the processor usage? It can be due to a memory leakage issue, or simply that there is not enough ram for the system to use so it uses swap memory (and disk writes are always slower).

Comment: @AtifAnwer Hi, thanks for your comment, the processor usage peaks at 29% and the RAM usage peaks at 41% during runtime.